# Cómo añadir una propiedad personalizada de usuario desde una DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, identity

Estoy utilizando MVC 5, code first y EF6. 
Parto de el proyecto que se crea desde VS con la plantilla MVC y la opción "Cuentas de usuario individuales"

Intento añadir una propiedad (departamento) al usuario basada en una clase creada por mi. El valor de dicha propiedad se ha de 
seleccionar desde una DropdownList en la vista de registro de nuevo usuario.

La clase Departamento está definida en el modelo así:

```
public class Departamento
{
   [Key]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string CodigoDepartamento { get; set; }
   public string NombreDepartamento { get; set; }
}
```

La añado al usuario de la siguiente manera:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public Departamento Departamento { get; set; }

   public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
   {
      var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
      return userIdentity;
   }
}
```

He modificado la clase RegisterViewModel añadiendo la propiedad así:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Departamento")]
public Departamento Departamento { get; set; }
```

En AccountController.cs he modificado el método de acción (GET) Register() para utilizar el ViewBag (no se si es la forma más correcta de hacerlo, estoy empezando con MVC)
para pasarle la lista de departamentos a la vista de esta manera:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
   var deptQuery = db.Departamentos.OrderBy(d => d.NombreDepartamento).ToList();
   ViewBag.departamentos = new SelectList(deptQuery, "ID", "NombreDepartamento");
   return View();
}
```

El método de acción (POST) Register() queda así:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, Departamento = model.Departamento};
      var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
      ...resto de código
   }
}
```

En la vista de registro de nuevo usuario (Register.cshtml) he incluido la DropdownList así:

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Departamento, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Departamento, 
                            new SelectList(ViewBag.departamentos, "ID", "NombreDepartamento"), 
                            "Seleccionar un departamento", 
                            new { @class = "form-control" })

   </div>
</div>
```

Ahora mismo, al acceder a la vista me da el siguiente error:

System.Web.HttpException: 'DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' no contiene una propiedad con el nombre 'ID'.'

¿Cómo debería plantearlo para poder hacer esto?

Comentar también que quiero poder asignar al DropDwonListFor la clase "form-control" para que el aspecto sea similar al resto de controles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema es que solo has definido una propiedad de navegación para `Departamento` en `ApplicationUser`, te falta definir la llave del Departamento ejemplo:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public int DepartamentoID { get; set; }
   public Departamento Departamento { get; set; }

   public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
   {
      var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
      return userIdentity;
   }
}
```

También debes modificar RegisterViewModel. Para esto cambia `Departamento` por `DepartamentoID` ejmplo:

```
   public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Departamento")]
        public int DepartamentoID { get; set; }
...
}
```

y en tu Controlador:

```
   // GET: /Account/Register
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            ViewBag.DepartamentoID = new SelectList( db.Departamentos.OrderBy( d => d.NombreDepartamento ), "ID", "NombreDepartamento");
            return View();
        }
```

tu método de acción create de tipo POST debe quedar de esta forma:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, DepartamentoID = model.DepartamentoID };
      var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
      ...resto de código
   }
}
```

Como ves se ha cambiado `Departamento` que es una propiedad de navegación por `DepartamentoID` que es la llave foranea que necesita EF para guardar en tu BD.

y en la vista puedes llamar el DropDown de esta forma:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DepartamentoID, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("DepartamentoId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Vicente, con la solución que me propones me da el siguiente error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'El elemento ViewData con la clave 'DepartamentoID' es de tipo 'System.Int32' pero debe ser de tipo 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.' Me lo marca en la línea:  @Html.DropDownList("DepartamentoID", null, "Seleccionar un departamento", new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: Amigo ese ejemplo lo he reproducido en mi PC y fuanciona perfectamente repasa bien todo lo que te he puesto paso a paso y no olvides realizar una Migración, debes ver en tu tabla AspNetUsers el campo DepartamentoID

Comment: Ya he encontrado el problema. En el viewmodel falta esta línea: public IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> Departamentos { get; set; }